# Android App for Converting Temperatures is crashing

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am to make an app that converts between Farhenheit and Celsius, and also implement a dropdown menu (spinner) which displays the next 5 temperatures and their corresponding conversions.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;


import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private EditText temp;
    private RadioButton toC;
    private RadioButton toF;
    private Button ConvertButton;
    private Spinner nextTempsSpinner;
    private String tempText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Assigning the private Java variables to their XML counterparts

        temp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTemperature); //Text box where user enters temperature
        toC = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.FtoC); //Radio Button user selects so that temperature will be interpreted as Fahrenheit and returned as Celsius
        toF = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.CtoF); //Radio Button user selects so that temperature will be interpreted as Fahrenheit and returned as Celsius
        ConvertButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.GetConversion); //Button user will click to get the conversion
        nextTempsSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinMyTemps); //Spinner is the drop down menu where the next 5 conversions will appear

        ConvertButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Double temporary, answer, temporaryTemperature;

        String goingFrom = null; //Adding these so that we can use these strings in the dropdown spinner
        String goingTo = null;

        double value = Double.valueOf(temp.getText().toString());
        if (toC.isChecked()) // If the radio button for converting from Fahrenheit to Celsius is selected this conversion will happen
        {
            value = UnitConverter.FahrenheitToCelsius(value);
            goingFrom = "F";
            goingTo = "C";
        } else if (toF.isChecked()) // If the radio button for converting from Celsius to Fahrenheit is selected this conversion will happen
        {
            value = UnitConverter.CelsiusToFahrenheit(value);
            goingFrom = "C";
            goingTo = "F";
        }
        temp.setText(Double.valueOf(value).toString());

        DecimalFormat twoDecimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");


        temporaryTemperature = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(temp));

        //Creating ArrayAdapter

        List<String> listOfTemps = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayAdapter getTempAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listOfTemps);
        getTempAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            answer = Double.parseDouble(twoDecimalFormat.format(temp));
            temporary = temporaryTemperature + i;
            tempText = temporary.toString();
            tempText = tempText + " " + goingFrom + " = ";
            tempText = tempText + answer.toString();
            tempText = tempText + " " + goingTo;
            listOfTemps.add(tempText);
        }
        nextTempsSpinner.setAdapter(getTempAdapter);
    }
}
```

And yes, I do have a Java file called UnitConverter and that has nothing special in it, just this

```
public class UnitConverter {
    public static double CelsiusToFahrenheit(double c){
        return 32+c*9/5;
    }

    public static double FahrenheitToCelsius(double f){
        return (f-32)*5/9;
    }
}
```

The conversion part definitely works, as do the radio buttons, the convert button. Somewhere in the onClick method as I was coding the spinner, it seems to have gone haywire and now the entire app crashes. Thanks for your help guys.

EDIT: The logcat information is as follows:

```
08-13 15:30:31.557 2398-2398/com.aly.converttemps I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)

                                                         [ 08-13 15:30:31.610  1580: 1601 D/         ]
                                                         HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7f0863664ec0, tid 1601
08-13 15:30:31.632 2398-2398/com.aly.converttemps W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.aly.converttemps-2/lib/x86_64
08-13 15:30:36.881 2398-2398/com.aly.converttemps W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.aly.converttemps-2/lib/x86_64
08-13 15:30:37.106 2398-2548/com.aly.converttemps D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

                                                                    [ 08-13 15:30:37.113  2398: 2398 D/         ]
                                                                    HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7f086f9941c0, tid 2398


                                                                    [ 08-13 15:30:37.152  2398: 2548 D/         ]
                                                                    HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7f086f994440, tid 2548
08-13 15:30:37.163 2398-2548/com.aly.converttemps I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4

                                                                    [ 08-13 15:30:37.198  1209: 2251 D/         ]
                                                                    HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7f4b63d56500, tid 2251
08-13 15:30:45.585 2398-2398/com.aly.converttemps D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


                                                                    --------- beginning of crash
08-13 15:30:45.586 2398-2398/com.aly.converttemps E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: com.aly.converttemps, PID: 2398
                                                                    java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "android.widget.EditText{1495b6d VFED..CL. .F....ID 42,42-592,144 #7f0b0003 app:id/editTemperature}"
                                                                        at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
                                                                        at java.lang.StringToReal.initialParse(StringToReal.java:114)
                                                                        at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:282)
                                                                        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
                                                                        at com.aly.converttemps.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:75)
                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: if is crashing then post the logCat-ErrorMEssage-StackTrace... we need that information

Comment: Can you please post the whole trace?

Comment: Hi, yes I have just added the logcat error message (sorry about the formatting)

Comment: Try to set adapter in onCreate instead of onClick...

Comment: `com.aly.converttemps.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:75)` This means the problem starts at line 75 in MainActivity.java. Which line is this? The error message also indicates that you are not sending a valid numerical string to be converted into a numerical value.

Answer (score 3):

You are passing editText Object's reference as String in parseDouble(String).

change :

```
 temporaryTemperature = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(temp));
```

to :

```
 temporaryTemperature = Double.parseDouble(temp.getText().toString());
```

or :

```
 temporaryTemperature = Double.valueOf(temp.getText().toString())
```

Comment: Both lines of code given here give equivalent results. They both convert a `double` into a `String` representation. Granted the second is shorter and probably preferred. However, this line is **not** the cause of the error. The stacktrace indicates the problem is at a line which calls `Double.parseDouble()`.

Comment: Tried this just now, but my app is still crashing. I'm going to try restarting my computer because it's suddenly also gotten extremely slow as has the emulator. But also, apart from the actual converting portion of the functionality, does the code I wrote for the spinner and loading the ArrayAdapter into it work or is there something wrong with that too (that maybe the log cat didn't get to yet)

Answer (score 1):

Look at this line of code:

```
temporaryTemperature = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(temp));
```

The variable `temp` is declared as:

```
private EditText temp;
```

Note that `temp` is an `EditText`. The only version of `String.valueOf()` which matches this call is [the one which takes an `Object` parameter](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)). This is the same as calling `temp.toString()` which prints the class name and some other information about the `EditText` object.

You need to retrieve the text which was typed by the user:

```
temporaryTemperature = Double.parseDouble(temp.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Tried this just now, but my app is still crashing. I'm going to try restarting my computer because it's suddenly also gotten extremely slow as has the emulator. But also, apart from the actual converting portion of the functionality, does the code I wrote for the spinner and loading the ArrayAdapter into it work or is there something wrong with that too (that maybe the log cat didn't get to yet)

Comment: @butimnotarapper The code initializing the spinner looks mostly right. However, `listOfTemps` is empty, so no items will be listed in the spinner. I suggest that you learn about [string array resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray). If you have any more questions about this, you should post a brand new question.